# android:layout_height not working for CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am working with CardViews inside a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. The problem that I am facing is, *the height I specify for the card view inside xml or in java, it doesn't get enforced by the CardView*. It seems like the **cumulative height of the child views of the CardView becomes the height of the CardView**. This behavior considering the fact that it's parent's layout parameters that are enforced on its child views.

What am I missing? Am I doing something wrong?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_view_width"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"

    >

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="@dimen/card_view_width"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
></ImageView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In this case the height of the card view is 0dp but still the layout designer preview & when the app runs on the device, the size of the card is 10dp.

Best Regards

Comment: Any one here to help?

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to happen, with what you told the program?

You tell the `CardVeiw` to have a height of `0dp` with this:
    android:layout_height="0dp"

Then you place an `ImageView` inside, and tell it to have a height of `10dp`.

So of course the `CardView` makes itself taller to allow the `ImageView` to fit properly.

If you want the inner elements to match the height of the `CardView`, set the `layout_height` of the `CardView` to whatever you want, like `20dp`:

```
android:layout_height="20dp"
```

Then have the inner elements `match_parent`:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: I have tried with match_parent as well. It didn't work out. Besides I can't totally avoid numbers, in certain views I have to use margin top & bottoms and they are also added to the cardview. This is the behavior I face when using other viewgroups

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting visibility to 0? IF you are trying to hide it, use `visibility = View.GONE'.

ALso, don't use `elevation` which won't work before L. Insteed, use [cardElevation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation) so that it will work before L as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** in your CardView.